# Clearing i on an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm having an issue clearing i on this equation, I've tried online step by step problem solvers but for some reason they give false as if there is no solution

This is how i write the equation on those sites to clear "i", any suggestion?

> ## $$98000=2350 \times \frac{(1+i)^{40}-1}{(1+i)^{40}i}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Here's a hint:  what is $(i+1)^2$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner isn't it 2i ?

Comment: Yes; what's $(i+1)^4=((i+1)^2)^2$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner 4i = 4i, still missing the big picture though

Comment: $(2i)^2=-4$; you should then be able to compute $(1+i)^{40}=((1+i)^4)^{10}$ fairly easily

Comment: So `40i = ((4i)^10` ? Apologies if i'm still lost here

Comment: Are you sure you have written the equation correctly? It is false as written?

Comment: It's correctly written.

Comment: $(1+i)^{40}=(-4)^{10}=2^{20}=1024^2=1048576$; I have been assuming $i^2=-1$

Comment: If $i$ is an unknown rather than the square root of $-1$, have look at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+98000%2F2350+%3D+%28%281%2Bx%29%5E40-1%29+%2F%28x*+%281%2Bx%29%5E40%29). It gives two real solutions: $i = -1.89622\dots$ and $i = -0.00201752\dots$

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you compute $(1+i)^2$, and then you should be able to compute $(1+i)^{40}$ fairly easily.

Comment: Still having issues clearing i step by step.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+i)^2 = 1+2i-1 = 2i$

$(1+i)^4 = ((1+i)^2)^2 =(2i)^2=-4$

$(1+i)^{40}=((1+i)^{4})^{10}=(-4)^{10}=2^{20}$

$$\frac{(1+i)^{40}-1}{(1+i)^{40}i}=\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{(1+i)^{40}i}$$

Substituting $(1+i)^{40}=2^{20}$ and $1/i=-i$

$$\implies-i+i(2^{-40})$$

$$\implies i(2^{-40}-1)$$

This is a **pure imaginary number**. Your equation in the question is wrong.

Comment: So there's no solution, i was under the idea the result should be 0,01524, but i find no way in which it can give that result. :/

Comment: More like false statement. Solution is when you have a variable in the equation.